# Access Database - Export to .CSV Outputs Code instead of Text

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I have been running a simple database that reformats Excel data, and outputs it to a .csv file in order to import into our accounting software. A few minor tweaks were made to a query, and now the .csv file has unusable data formatting. It appears to be some sort of code instead of simple text. I simply can't figure out what is going on to have changed this.

I use this VBA string on the Main Form:

```
Private Sub COGenerate_Click()
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, _
TableName:="07 CO Material Output Format", FileName:="G:\pathname\File.CSV"
End Sub
```

This is the SQL format of the referenced query:

```
SELECT [Forms]![Main]![JobNumber] AS Job, [Forms]![Main]![CONumber] AS COName, Left([F10],2) AS CCLetter, Mid([F10],3,5) AS CCNumber, "" AS [Empty 1], "" AS [Empty 2], [Forms]![Main]![COName] AS CODescrip, [Cost Elements].[Type Code], "" AS [Empty 3], "" AS [Empty 4], "1" AS One, "" AS [Empty 5], IIf([F10]='CM01701' Or [F10]='CM01702' Or [F10]='CM01703' Or [F10]='dm00100' Or [F10]='dm00101' Or [F10]='dm00102',[sum of MatUnit],1) AS Units, [02 Material Pivot].[Per Unit Cost], [Units]*[Per Unit Cost] AS Total
FROM [02 Material Pivot] INNER JOIN [Cost Elements] ON [02 Material Pivot].F10 = [Cost Elements].[Cost Code];
```

In the output, the form input boxes that previously outputted without a problem now look like this:

"ABC" in the box shows as "41 00 42 00 43 00" in the .csv. However, within Access, the query looks appropriate.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What program are you using to look at the CSV file? To clarify: what you are seeing is the hexadecimal representation of the text as Unicode characters - and most likely UTF-16. VBA natively uses UTF-8 as far as I know, so I find it odd, but maybe there's a setting for it. The first thing to determine is whether it's a problem with the viewing software and not the export itself.

Comment: I normally use Excel to view the CSV file. However, we typically don't open this particular file, we run the import process and review the import verification screen. This is where we first noticed the Unicode characters. I have confirmed the Unicode is still there when opening with Notepad as well.

Comment: See this related question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344668/microsoft-access-transfertext-function-problem-with-codepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recreated the entire database from scratch, thinking there was something formatted oddly somewhere. However I was still getting the Unicode data in the export. I went to a similar database I use, and tried a similar export process, which worked without issue.

The main difference between the 2 seemed to be attempting the export from a Union Query rather than a regular query. The union worked, even though the SQL code is the same. In order to get this working in the new database, I made a redundant union query, which had the same SQL code twice. The output was the same as if there was only one, and the export worked fine.

Very odd, very frustrating, but it is working now!

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code and I did not see any problem. It exported my data successfully so I guess there should be something with your data in the tables. I recommend doing the exportation process manually since ACCESS UI will give you more visibility on the process. You can save exportation and do it with one click later so there is no need to fix the code.

There are a lot more options out there to control the exportation. Use Export Text file. When you see the propsed file name and extension (txt) change txt to csv manually. It will work. After going to the next step, click the ADVANCED button to control all of the formatting and character conversion etc.

It is difficult to see what the exact problem is since we don't have access to your tables and their data, but this should work file for you.

Comment: It won't let me export this manually via the Export>Text File options. If I don't select "Export data with formatting and layout" then I get an error message - "Too few parameters. Expected 3."
If I do select the option, the data is not usable as it doesn't have the right breaks in the data. I never get to a screen allowing advanced options. 
I appreciate the effort though!